# Runtime Error in code - "NumberFormatException"

Tags: java

This is a program to display the cheapest pair of shoes. The data is from a text file. After I put in the color, manufacturer, and type of shoe, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Price"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Boots.main(Boots.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I am at my wits' end. Please help!

Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Boots
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

   String manufact, color, type; 

   System.out.print("Enter the boot manufacturer."); 
   manufact = keyboard.nextLine(); 
   manufact = manufact.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); 
   System.out.print("Enter the type of boot."); 
   type = keyboard.nextLine();  
   type = type.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); 
   System.out.print("Enter the boot color."); 
   color = keyboard.nextLine();     
   color = color.replaceAll("\\s+", "");    

   /* Open boots.txt.*/

    File inputFile = new File("Boots.txt"); 
    if (!inputFile.exists()) System.out.print("I'm sorry, we are experiencing technical difficulties. Please try again later."); 
    Scanner warehouse = new Scanner(inputFile); 

    String[] compData = new String[25]; 

    int price = 0; // cheapest pair of shoes 
    String finalVendor = ""; 
    String finalType = ""; 
    String finalManufact = ""; 
    String finalColor = ""; //information of cheapest pair of shoes

    /* Read through file, and save each line as a compData array, each word tokenized as a compData subarray.*/ 

    do {
      String nLine = warehouse.nextLine(); 
      StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(nLine);
      for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            {
             compData[i] = tokens.nextToken(); 
            }

      int priceParsed = Integer.parseInt(compData[4]); 
      if (compData[1].equalsIgnoreCase(manufact))
            if (compData[3].equalsIgnoreCase(color))
                if (compData[2].equalsIgnoreCase(type))
                    if (priceParsed <= price) 
                      { 
                        price = priceParsed; 
                        finalVendor = compData[0]; finalManufact = compData[1]; finalType = compData[2]; finalColor=compData[3]; 
      }
    } while (warehouse.hasNext());

    if (price<=0)
    {System.out.printf("Meet your new shoes!\nThey are %s %s by %s. You can get them for $%.2s at %s.", finalColor, 
                       finalType, finalVendor, finalManufact, price);} else {System.out.print("We have no such merchandise at this time.");};

    warehouse.close(); 
    keyboard.close(); 
  }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that `if(priceParsed <= price)` is never true. in such a case you will receive such errors. you can deal with it my initializing then with `null`. and `system.out.printf` will tell you if the condition was ever true, given that comData[i] is never `null`.

Comment: If one of those if statements fails, then you never give values to those variables and then when you get to the line where you print, they will be null. Just do `String finalVendor = "";` for them instead of starting them as null.

Comment: Have you checked what is inside the array after tokenizing?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add = ""; to the end of the String variable declaration.

```
String finalVendor = ""; 
String finalType = ""; 
String finalManufact = ""; 
String finalColor = ""; //information of cheapest pair of shoes
```

this will get rid of your errors.
If you are having a problem with parseInt you need to check what is in the array you are looking at and make sure you are getting the right data from your tokenizer.

Comment: Thanks! Why do I need to initialize them?

Comment: Basic, you cannot access variables that are not initialized. you get an error as you are getting now.

Comment: Think of it this way, Java does what C and C++ does not, it protects you from bad programming practices, if you create a variable the compiler sets aside a specific amount for that variable, most likely there is something that the system no longer cares about in that location just junk, so if you access that memory area without initializing it first it can create memory leakage.

Comment: But I already said that `finalVendor = compData[0]; finalManufact = compData[1]; finalType = compData[2]; finalColor=compData[3];`, why didn't that work?

Comment: David, what do you mean by memory leakage?

Comment: When a program can read un-initialized data and act upon that data or leaves full uncorrupted data in memory that can then be accessed by a program or something else.  That is memory leakage

Comment: Your code above does not show the initialization with the compData[] array, only the String finalVendor; ect.  That is the initialization there not what you do after it.